# how to determine the cipher suites supported by a SERVER?

Tags: tls, server

I somehow was not able to find an answer.  I can see the ciphersuits supported by the client/browser on the wire, but server does NOT appear to advertise the ciphersuites it supports during the handshake.  But I know SSLLab's SSL tester does provide a report of the ciphersuites a SERVER would support.  How was that done?  One possibility is for the client to try ALL possibilities one at a time?

Comment: **Yes they try one at a time**, and so do many other tools that do this. See http://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers for several scripts and links to at least a dozen more, and that doesn't count loads of commercial or otherwise restricted products.

Comment: Thanks.  That's very helpful.  I somehow didn't find it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I use this nmap script, it's convenient and gives scores similar to Qualys SSL Labs:

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html