# On a openSSL server, is it possible to see what kind of ciphers are supported?

Tags: openssl

I need to provide a screenshot to show what kind of ciphers are supported on my openSSL server. Is there a command for this? or is this something i need to find elsewhere?

Comment: More context needed. Do you care what your version of OpenSSL supports, or what ciphers the application using OpenSSL allows?

Comment: You will want to make your question more clear, at a guess, do you want to check the supported ciphers for a server, similar to how [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) does?

Comment: When you connect part of the negotiation is the server telling you what ciphers it supports.

Comment: @Daisetsu: The server does not tell the client which cipher it supports. The client tells instead the server which ciphers it supports and the server will then pick one from this. One can kind of deduct from this which ciphers are supported by the server by just trying all imaginable ciphers and see if it works but there can be other factors apart from the ciphers, like some ciphers only supported with specific ECC curves, with specific certificates (ECC vs RSA key) ... so it is not that simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to test whether a server supports any cipher suite?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136318/), [how to determine the cipher suites supported by a SERVER?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120008), [Finding the cipher suites supported by a web server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124629), [How does a client (like SSLLabs) know all the cipher suites a server supports if the server doesn’t send its list of supported cipher suites?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187010).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a command for this?

```
openssl ciphers 'ALL'
```

will list all the encrypting ciphers.

```
openssl ciphers 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL'
```

will list all ciphers.

If you want to confirm the list, you could use a script to cycle through each cipher and try to connect a tls-client with that cipher. You might also want to cycle over version as well, this is illustrated in this [example bash script](https://www.securityevaluators.com/using-openssl-determine-ciphers-enabled-server/)